# How do I get ~/.XCompose to work on QT applications while using Ibus?

Tags: qt, ibus

I'm trying to use `~/.XCompose` in Qt programs like Anki, but they don't recognize my settings (<kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> giving *ª* instead of *ā*, for example).

Most help guides online tell me to set `QT_IM_MODULE` to XIM, but I also want to use ibus. Is there a way I can get XCompose to work in Qt programs and keep ibus?

Answer (score 1):

Install the `ibus-qt4` package, otherwise the QT4 programs will not work.